# Compare two alphanumeric variables mixed with special expression in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to compare two alphanumeric strings and below is the bash expression I think should do the job. But I'm getting blank result. Please advise.

```
:~$ echo $tempnow $threshold
+60.0°C +80.0°C

:~$ res=`echo "$tempnow $threshold" | awk '{ if($1 > $2) print "Exceeds"; else echo "Normal" }'`
:~$ echo $res

:~$
```

Comment: I suggest to insert `tr -d '+°C' |` before `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `echo` in awk.

You can use:

```
echo '+90.0°C +80.0°C' | awk '{ print ($1+0 > $2+0 ? "Exceeds" : "Normal") }'
Exceeds

echo '+60.0°C +80.0°C' | awk '{ print ($1+0 > $2+0 ? "Exceeds" : "Normal") }'
Normal
```

Also note use of `+0` to convert fields into numeric values.

Comment: Ahh ... had missed it. Thanks a lot. Still unable to figure out why below code fails complaining syntax error 'else'. 

`if [ "$res" -eq "Exceeds" ]
then
  echo "Temperature exceeds threshold. Triggering mail to system owners..."
  mail -s "CPU temperature too high on system" abc@xyz.com
elif [ "$res" -eq "Normal" ]
  echo "Temperature under limit. Ignoring countermeasures!"
else
  echo "Unable to determine value"
fi`

Comment: `-eq` is for comparing numbers. Use [[ $res == "Exceeds" ]]` condition.

Answer (score 1):

You have written `echo` instead of `print` in your awk script.

This will be interpreted as the name of a function or variable, which doesn't exist, then it will be coerced to an empty string and concatenated with the string "Normal". The result will be discarded.

I would recommend writing your script as follows:

```
res=$(awk '{ print ($1 > $2 ? "Exceeds" : "Normal") }' <<<"$tempnow $threshold")
```

This uses `<<<` to pass the string over standard input to awk. The result of the ternary operator is printed and stored in the variable `$res`.

Bear in mind that you are currently comparing strings, so you will run into problems in situations such as this:

```
$ tempnow=+9.0°C
$ threshold=+80.0°C
$ awk '{ print ($1 > $2 ? "Exceeds" : "Normal") }' <<<"$tempnow $threshold"
Exceeds
```

Answer (score 0):

try below :-

```
res=`echo "$tempnow $threshold" | awk '{ if($1 > $2) print "Exceeds"; else print "Normal" }'`
```

Comment: Some explanation of what was wrong with the original code, as well as what this does differently, would make this a better answer.